# Java - Calling a secondary class from another class

Tags: java, mysql, class

I am not a java developer but I need to update some java code that reads RFID tags to then update our MySQL database. I have two working examples where I can read some tags in one file and I can update the database in another file but when combining them I am out of my league.

I added public static void JavaDatabaseUpdate to my working code for the RFID reader and as long as I don't call it, the code executes fine. The problem comes when I try to run the script... Maybe I am just approaching this all wrong:

```
public class ReadingTags {

static final String DEFAULT_READER_IP_ADDRESS = "192.168.1.5";
static final int PORT_NUMBER = 5000;
static final int maxResponseSize = 1000;
static RFIDReader reader = null;
public static boolean reading = false;

public static void main(String[] args){
    try
    {
        String readerIPAddress = DEFAULT_READER_IP_ADDRESS;
        int PortNumber = PORT_NUMBER;

        System.out.println("Setting up ReaderComm instance on IP Address " + readerIPAddress);
        
        reader = new RFIDReader(readerIPAddress, PortNumber);
        ReadTest();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Main: " + ex.toString());
    }
}


public static void ReadTest() throws Exception, InterruptedException
{
    TagReadHandler tagReadHandler = new TagReadHandler();
    ReadingTags.reader.SetTagReadCallback(tagReadHandler);
    System.out.println("Starting Continuous Read ...");
    ReadingTags.reading = true;
    ReadingTags.reader.StartContinuousRead();
    
    // Read for .050 seconds then issue stop command
    Thread.sleep(50);
    
    System.out.println("*** Stopping Continuous Read For 5 Seconds to wait on another tray. We would do an update here****");
    ReadingTags.reader.StopContinuousRead();
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    //Now start a new loop  
    System.out.println("Start New Loop");
    ReadTest();
    
    
    //While loop to read queued up
    //tag data and to wait for stop command response.
    
    
    while(ReadingTags.reading)
    {   
        Thread.sleep(10);
    } 
}

    public static void JavaDatabaseUpdate(String[] args) {
       Connection conn = null;
       Statement stmt = null;
       String rfid = "145131000000000000000000";
       try {
          try {
             Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
          } catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println(e);
          }
          conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/office", "root", "");
          stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
          String query1 = "update productiontrays set status=5 " + "where rfid ="+rfid;
          stmt.executeUpdate(query1);
          System.out.println("Record has been updated in the table successfully");
       } catch (SQLException excep) {
          excep.printStackTrace();
       } catch (Exception excep) {
          excep.printStackTrace();
       } finally {
          try {
             if (stmt != null)
             conn.close();
          } catch (SQLException se) {}
          try {
             if (conn != null)
             conn.close();
          } catch (SQLException se) {
             se.printStackTrace();
          }
       }
    }
```

}

And then the class where I would like to call the JavaDatabaseUpdate:

```
class TagReadHandler implements OnTagReadResponse{
public void handleTagRead(TagReadInfo readInfo)
{
    if (readInfo.tagReadStatus == 0) // STATUS_OK
    {
        System.out.println(readInfo.EPC.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", ""));
        //I'd like to call JavaDatabaseUpdate(); here with the EPC value passed along for the update
    }
    else if (readInfo.tagReadStatus == 1) // STATUS_DONE
    {
        ReadingTags.reading = false;
        System.out.println("Received Stop Response");
    }
}
```

}

I really need to pass that EPC value back to the class and update the database. How should I approach this situation? I'm stuck.

Comment: You haven't said what the problem is, but you should be able to just use: `ReadingTags.JavaDatabaseUpdate(...)` to call the method. It isn't clear what you want to pass, as `JavaDatabaseUpdate` doesn't use any of its parameters. I would change JavaDatabaseUpdate to take a single `String` parameter and use it wherever it is meant to be used, replacing `rfid` maybe?

Comment: Thank you. This got me going in the right direction. Appreciate the time!